# Referencing PermissionSetGroup in Validation Rules?

Tags: permission-set-groups

Is it possible to reference PermissionSetGroups in Validation Rules (and other tools)?

I dont see any reference in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_considerations.htm&type=5) describing this. User Assignment and defining every permission using $Permission seems redundant/counter-productive if they're already part of a Group. Any guidance would be helpful - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible - you can only reference Custom Permissions (`$Permission.xxx`) in a Validation Rule.

- A custom permission belongs to a Permission Set
- A Permission Set belongs (optionally) to a PermissionSet Group

So, one approach would be to create a PermissionSet that contains solely the Custom Permission and assign that PermissionSet to the PermissionSetGroup(s) that you want to check in the Validation Rule.